# How to change pivot table option using xlwings?

Tags: xlwings

When I make the pivot table in Excel, I usually use pivot table option and change to 'Classic Pivot table
layout'

I want to do it by using xlwings

Would you give me any suggetions?

Thank you.

I tried to find it but I couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

By recording a macro of selecting 'Classic PivotTable layout' in the Display tab of PivotTable Options, is returned the following:

```vb
Range("G8").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").InGridDropZones = True
```

To set this via xlwings you can call the `.api` in the worksheet with (this does select the tickbox in the options):

```py
ws = wb.sheets("Sheet1")
ws.api.PivotTables("PivotTable1").InGridDropZones = True
```